# Issue with custom jquery in bootstrap site

Tags: jquery, html, .net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show/hide a div in a bootstrap site I am developing, in a way I think should be pretty simple.

Div with ID "menu" should show when div with ID "btn" is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="btnjumpmenu" id="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span> Jump to...</div>
<div class="jumpmenu" id="menu"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#menu').slideDown('slow', function () {
    });
});
```

I've added the jquery function to the site.js file which is referenced, along with the jquery library by default in my _layout.cshtml file.

Unfortunately, this isn't working and I can't work out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's likely that your site.js is being loaded and run before #btn is available.  Wrap your code in a document.ready, ie `$(function() { $("#btn").click....`

Comment: Add to your code (at the top level, not inside the click handler): `alert($("#btn").length)` if it's zero, then "#btn" doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Add you code to the bottom of your html page (.cshtml?) in a `<script>` tag - does it work there?

Comment: Hi, the alert comes back with a value of 1

Comment: Thanks fore the tip, I've tried it in a script tag, it doesn't work

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "this isn't working".

Comment: What if you add an `alert` inside the click handler? Do you get that alert (confirm the click works on the button and thus it's the slideDown that's not working).

Comment: By not working, I meant that nothing was happening on click. It's OK I've got it working now with the below answer. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a habit of using jquery's ".on()" function.. it's just good practice for when you add items that need to be controlled dynamically on the page. The syntax is to target the fixed container, then .on(event,target,function())

http://api.jquery.com/on/

It isn't a requirement, though to be clear.

What is missing here is that you need to set your css so the display of your jumpmenu is display: none; in css and then let it slideDown upon clicking the btnjumpmenu:

css:

```
#menu{display: none;}
```

jquery / js:

```
$('body').on("click","#btn",function() {
    $('#menu').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sj7o8hw3/

Comment: This has got it working - thanks. Just an extra bonus, how can I expand on this to toggle slide up and slide down? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome! Check out .slideToggle() instead of .slideDown() - the .slideToggly() fuction will the targeted elements display state, and take the appropriate action. http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/